# Google Chrome App Chrome Managemement Licence Serial Number in Kiosk Mode

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there anyway to get a Chrome Management Licence device serial number or unique identifier within a Chrome Kiosk App?

I am asking this as we are trying to post unique content to each kiosk and using a uuid such as serial number is an obvious way to do this.

I realise that without the chrome management licence getting a serial number or uuid is not possible due to privacy but i am hoping there is a way with the chrome management licence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes

Only work on enrolled devices where the app is pushed from the cpanel

```
chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(function callback)
```

Comment: To make it a good Stack Overflow answer, could you please copy some relevant parts in the answer here?

Comment: thanks @Xan, updated the answer with your suggestion

Comment: @Spencer How did you get this to work? AFAIK Kiosk mode only allows apps and not extension, and enterprise.deviceAttributes is part of the extensions api?

Comment: IIRC, this is also an app api. Did you try using it?